# how to use is null with case statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Hi can any one say me how to write query in sql server management studio for statement =>`if(isnull("GROSS_SF")=1 or "GROSS_SF"=0,0,"GROSS_SALES"/"GROSS_SF")`
by using case statement :

```
  CASE 
 WHEN ("GROSS_SF"=1 or "GROSS_SF"=0) isnull   then 0
  else "GROSS_SALES"/"GROSS_SF"
  end/* i am getting error if i write it like this */
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain your intended logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid a divide by zero, while at the same time also handling `NULL`, then you may try the following logic:

```
CASE WHEN COALESCE(GROSS_SF, 0) = 0
     THEN 0
     ELSE GROSS_SALES / GROSS_SF END AS output
```

To be clear, the above logic would return a zero value should either the `GROSS_SF` be zero or `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what are you looking for is IFNULL, look here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  You can do:

```
(CASE WHEN "GROSS_SF" IS NULL OR "GROSS_SF" = 0 THEN 0
      ELSE "GROSS_SALES" / "GROSS_SF"
 END)
```

In SQL, divide by zero errors are often avoided using `NULLIF()`:

```
"GROSS_SALES" / NULLIF("GROSS_SF", 0)
```

However, that returns `NULL` rather than `0`.  If you really want zero:

```
COALESCE("GROSS_SALES" / NULLIF("GROSS_SF", 0), 0)
```

This is a bit shorter to write and almost equivalent to your version (this returns `0` if `"GROSS_SALES"` is `NULL`, which your version does not).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NULLIF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to prevent arithmetic `divide by zero errors` :

```
select . . . , 
      GROSS_SALES / nullif(GROSS_SF, 0)
from table t;
```

However, this would return `null` instead of error, if you want to display `0` instead then you need to use `isnull()` (MS SQL Specific) or `coalesce()` (SQL Standard).

So, you can express it :

```
select . . . , 
       isnull(GROSS_SALES / nullif(GROSS_SF, 0), 0)
from table t;
```